# MATLAB figure exporting with black background

Tags: matlab-figure

I was saving MATLAB figures as usual, when I found that some would export with a black background, concealing the axis labels.  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MATLAB main window, or the figure window, go to

```
File > Preferences ... > Figure Copy Template > Copy Options
```

and select `Force white background`.